# Swift Collection conformance default

Tags: swift

In my app I've some objects that conform to Collection. I do this because then I get the for-loop syntax and all the filter/map/etc methods for free. But I noticed it is always to same. I've got an private array and I just forward the calls. So I thought I would wrap Collection protocol in another protocol like so:

```
protocol CollectionTrait: Collection {
    associatedtype CollectionType: Collection

    var _items: CollectionType { get }
}

extension CollectionTrait {
    var startIndex: CollectionType.Index {
        return _items.startIndex
    }

    var endIndex: CollectionType.Index {
        return _items.endIndex
    }

    func index(after i: CollectionType.Index) -> CollectionType.Index {
        return _items.index(after: i)
    }

    subscript(index: CollectionType.Index) -> CollectionType.Element {
        get {
            return _items[index]
        }
    }
}
```

And this can be used as follows:

```
class Words: CollectionTrait {
    let _items = [
        "foo", "bar", "baz"
    ]
}

let words = Words()
for word in words {
    print(word)
}
```

I feel like this is great, only problem I have now is that _items needs to be public, but I kinda want it to be private since I preferable don't wanna expose it. So for now I prefixed it with an underscore, to show it shouldn't be used. Does anybody know a way to force this behaviour? Or just in general a better way to avoid code duplication without inheritance (is not always possible in my case)

Comment: Why does `_items` need to be public? I assume you only need to use it in `CollectionTrait` and its extensions, right?

Comment: @SaagarJha Show me the code that makes this possible. You cannot define a private in a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with splitting your code up into multiple files, you can define `CollectionTrait` as a `private` protocol and conform to it with `fileprivate`. If, in one file, you have:

```
private protocol CollectionTrait: Collection {
    associatedtype CollectionType: Collection

    var _items: CollectionType { get }
}

extension CollectionTrait {
    var startIndex: CollectionType.Index {
        return _items.startIndex
    }

    var endIndex: CollectionType.Index {
        return _items.endIndex
    }

    func index(after i: CollectionType.Index) -> CollectionType.Index {
        return _items.index(after: i)
    }

    subscript(index: CollectionType.Index) -> CollectionType.Element {
        get {
            return _items[index]
        }
    }
}

class Words: CollectionTrait {
    fileprivate let _items = [
        "foo", "bar", "baz"
    ]
}
```

In another file, if you try to use `Words` you can:

```
let words = Words()
for word in words {
    print(word)
}
```

But trying to access `words._items` directly would be an error, since it's `fileprivate`.

Comment: But this way I can only use the CollectionTrait for all the classes in the same file right?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you'd need to put all derived classes in the same file.